# how to get rid of virtual ethernet adapters listing in ifconfig?

Tags: raspbian, ethernet

Not sure how the below virtual ether net adapter got created, but I want to get rid of these:

```
br-2f80507f7044 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:fb:87:2d:9c  
          inet addr:172.20.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::859c:69bb:6f65:c1fb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

br-45c9564871e5 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:71:40:64:c1  
          inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

br-fa97e62e0be6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:c7:dd:54:fa  
          inet addr:172.19.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the very bottom one seems to be plugged in and utilized?

Comment: but then I got rid of eth0 entry and that had different hardware address, then which one that might be, I have removed it from the list

Answer (score 1):

You add and remove bridges with the `brctl` command.

Comment: `~ $ brctl`
`-bash: brctl: command not found`

Comment: then edit /etc/network/interfaces and remove the br... interfaces. and then run `sudo service networking restart`. Ref.: https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections

Comment: `apt install apt-file; apt-file search brctl` ...

Comment: `apt-cache search brctl`

Comment: @MatsK That only works if you already have it installed ;)  If you don't, and you need to find the package that provides something, you need `apt-file`.

Comment: @goldilocks, Actually not, it gather the info (installed and not installed) from all sources, ref.: https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-cache.html

Comment: I have tried both the answers , it disappears but on reboot those bridge or veth adapters comes back

Comment: Well, all I can say is `apt-cache search brctl` returns nothing for me on a machine where it is not installed (and `apt-cache dumpavail | grep bridge-utils` returns nothing...).

Comment: Reinstall the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with ifconfig as well :

```
sudo ifconfig br-<number> down
```

Comment: Note that `ifconfig` is depreciated (see `man ifconfig`).  Also, placing an interface in a "down" state *does not* get rid of it.  By default `ifconfig` only shows interfaces in an "up" state, so it might *seem* to be gone, but it will appear in `ifconfig -a` (or `ip link`).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Although it does remove the virtual interfaces I create with the same tool.

Comment: I have tried both the answers , it disappears but on reboot those bridge or veth adapters comes back

Comment: You may try this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/624396/remove-network-interface-permanently